# Android AIDL, proguard, debug and release mode headaches

Tags: android, android-studio, aidl

This problem MAY be a result of the fact that my IPC service APKs (which are to run as independent processes) is configured as a *module* in Android Studio instead of a separate project. The project contains an app and three modules, one module is a Bluetooth library and the other two modules create the stand-alone IPC service APKs. The services are used by the Bluetooth library via AIDL. In debug mode, I can install the services from Android Studio as activity-less APKs. I can also install the primary app which uses the Bluetooth Library from Android Studio. It works fine in debug mode.

But as soon as I try and build the entire project in release mode, I get a build error when I try to install the service (not the primary app) that the AIDL APIs are duplicated (an identical classes.jar exists in the Bluetooth library 'build' directory as in the service build directory). The actual message is

```
Type com.pcha.proprietary.handler.IConnectionCallback$Default is defined multiple times:
```

Does any understand this? My guess is that if I made the service a *separate project* (which in Android Studio has to appear in a separate Window which is a pain) that it would be fine.

I have the latest version of AS as of 4/2/2020

I tried removing the copies of the AIDL files in the IPC service modules and pointed to the single AIDL file in the master Bluetooth service. Once again this did work in debug mode but as soon as I moved to release, I get the same defined multiple times error.

**Some progress**: In each of the IPC services I removed the AIDL directory and in the gradle.build file I excluded any references to aidl files in the source sets. This allows me to build in release mode AND debug mode, but the IPC and primary services only work if minifyEnabled false. In minfiyEnabled true the primary service does not find the IPC services.

Comment: You probably should check all of your dependencies and see if they have specific proguard configurations. You usually need to set some classes to -keep and it will work. What are your dependencies?

Comment: @AviParshan what is happening when using minifyEnabled true is that Android removes all the classes and methods that are not public. The end result is if your module is a library, you have to use proguard on the aar file generated with minifyEnabled false. So its a two step process - generate the aar, THEN use proguard separately. There are special proguard 'methods' to handle a library. Its kind of ugly but I have done in before on a smaller scale. You want to keep minifyEnabled out of the initial library build!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was more complicated than I thought. In debug mode it appears one can get away with anything. But not release.

The project has a single app that uses a Bluetooth library service and two IPC services. However, the IPC services are built as a module in the same project. Why? Android Studio in not Eclipse - only one project per Window! Modules, however, introduces problems. But here is how to get it to work in release with proguard minimification:

1. No copies of the AIDL files in the two module IPC services (as one would need if they were built as separate projects)
2. Do not reference the AIDL files in the IPC services gradle files (as one would need to do in an independent project).

This will allow one to build in release, deploy the two IPC service APKs and the application and run it IF 'minifyEnabled false' is set in each of the four build.gradle files.

If you want to set 'minifyEnabled true' to reduce the APK size of the app then ONLY do that in the application build.gradle file. However, be sure to 'keep' every AIDL interface and object you have defined. For example, in my local proguard file:

```
-keep class com.pcha.proprietary.handler.IConnectionCallback
-keep class com.pcha.proprietary.handler.IStatusEventCallback
-keep class com.pcha.proprietary.handler.IIntermediaryCallback
-keep class com.pcha.proprietary.handler.ILogCallback
-keep class com.pcha.btmanager.PhdInformation
-keep class com.pcha.btmanager.ProprietaryDriverPhdInfo
-keep class com.lni.codephg.inter.MdsIntermediary
-keep class com.lni.codephg.inter.CompoundEntry
-keep class com.lni.codephg.inter.EnumEntry
-keep class com.lni.codephg.inter.Facets
-keep class com.lni.codephg.inter.NumericEntry
-keep class com.lni.codephg.inter.ProfuctionSpecOid
-keep class com.lni.codephg.inter.RtsaEntry
-keep class com.lni.codephg.inter.SpecializationStruct
-keep class com.lni.codephg.fhir.MderFloat
-keep class com.lni.codephg.inter.TimeStruct
```

To minify the Bluetooth Library aars and the IPC service APKs requires more work that needs to be done independently of the build. Minifying library aars/jars requires a second handling of the built files...at least I know of no other way to do it.

However that goes beyond the original question but still something I want to do. Look for any help and further understanding of this mess.